# Stack trace of another process c using windows api

Tags: c, winapi

I would like to print/make a stacktrace of a running process from within my c application (not c++) using the windows api.

Currently I have this code:

```
void StackTrace(int pid)
{
  unsigned int i;
  void *stack[STACK_BUFFER];
  unsigned short frames;
  SYMBOL_INFO *symbol;
  HANDLE process;
  process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
  SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);
  frames = RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(0, STACK_BUFFER, stack, NULL);
  symbol = (SYMBOL_INFO *)calloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 256 * sizeof(char), 1);
  symbol->MaxNameLen = 255;
  symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);

  for (i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
      SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(stack[i]), 0, symbol);
      if (symbol->NameLen != 0)
          printf("%s at %09x\n", symbol->Name, symbol->Address);
  }
  free(symbol);
}
```

But the problem is that when I run it on a process it always gives me the same results, even when the application is stack tracing itself. Can you help me with this?

EDIT: The problem is that it always gives the same symbol name and address.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you specify which results it gives you, and which results you are expecting?

Comment: You should realise that this can never work because you don't pass RtlCaptureStackBackTrace any information about which thread is to be traced. A websearch would yield articles and example code for how to do this.

Comment: @ItamarG3 well first of it always shows the same symbol name and the same address no matter on which process i run it against

Comment: @MarinB Please include all the relevant details in the question itself. You can edit your post.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How would I pass that since there is no parameter that resembles what you are telling me?

Comment: No. There isn't is there. Clearly you've got the wrong function. Why did you think this would trace into a different process. Heck, you didn't even mention a thread anywhere. Which thread did you expect would be traced. Do some research like I said. Web search has the answers. Why do so many people not know about Web search?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5Dcapture+stack+trace

Answer (score 0):

You're capturing the stack trace of your current thread when you're using `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` in this way. I think that what you're looking for is: [StackWalkEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn280332(v=vs.85).aspx)